# WebpackError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, bulma

I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong here/how to fix it. I'm building a site using gatsby.js and bulma. It's my first time using either and I'm getting an issue when I try and build it that reads:

`WebpackError: document is not defined`

The only place I'm using `document` is with the navbar-burger toggle code provided in the bulma docs. Everything works fine in development but breaks when building for production. This is my code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import Logo from '../img/logo.png'

const Navbar = ({ siteTitle }) => (
  <div>
    <nav className="navbar is-primary is-fixed-top">
        <div className="container is-fluid">
            <div className="navbar-brand">
                <a className="navbar-item" href="../">
                    <img src={Logo} alt="Logo"/>
                </a>
                <a role="button" className="navbar-burger has-text-white" data-target="navMenu" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className="navbar-menu" id="navMenu">
                <div className="navbar-start has-text-white">
                      <a className="navbar-item">
                        Overview
                      </a>
                      <a className="navbar-item">
                        Overview
                      </a>
                      <a className="navbar-item">
                        Overview
                      </a>
                      <a className="navbar-item">
                        Overview
                      </a>

                </div>
                <div className="navbar-end has-text-white">
                    
                      <a className="has-text-white navbar-item">
                        Overview
                      </a>
                      <div className="navbar-item">
                      <a className="button is-success is-fullwidth">
                        Request Demo
                      </a>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

  </div>
    
);
    
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
        const $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

        // Check if there are any navbar burgers
        if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {

            // Add a click event on each of them
            $navbarBurgers.forEach(el => {
                el.addEventListener('click', () => {

                    // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
                    const target = el.dataset.target;
                    const $target = document.getElementById(target);

                    // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
                    el.classList.toggle('is-active');
                    $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

                });
            });
        }

    });

export default Navbar
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I don’t remember exactly what the fix was. I think I ended up deleting the node_modules folder, made sure the gatsby-cli was updated, then ran npm install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a client-side/server-side issue.

`document` is inherently client-side, since it represents the client's document. However, Gatsby renders your site server-side (when you run `gatsby build`).

`document` will be undefined on build, and trigger an error (see the docs page [Debugging HTML builds](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/)):

> Some of your code references “browser globals” like `window` or `document`. If this is your problem you should see an error above like “window is not defined”.

Gatsby suggests two solutions:

> To fix this, find the offending code and either
>
> 1. check before calling the code if window is defined so the code doesn’t run while Gatsby is building (see code sample below) or
> 2. if the code is in the render function of a React.js component, move that code into componentDidMount which ensures the code doesn’t run unless it’s in the browser.